# Class properties not holding values

Tags: c++, windows-console

im working in a text-based RPG game, but when I'm setting the values to X variable, when I access that propertie again, it is in its default value, am I doing something wrong?

```
class Game
{
private:
    bool podeAndar;
    bool estaBatalhando;
    Jogador _jogador;
    Mapa _mapa;
public:
    Game() { }

    Game(Jogador _j){
        _jogador = Jogador(_j.getNome());
        _mapa.LoadMapa();
        podeAndar = true;
        estaBatalhando = false;
    }

    ~Game(void)
    {
    }

    Jogador getJogador() {
        return _jogador;
    }

    void setJogador(Jogador v) {
        _jogador = v;
    }
}
```

My "Player" class

```
#pragma once
#include "Criatura.h"

#include <string>

class Jogador :
    public Criatura
{
private:
    int _cap;
public:

    Jogador(std::string nome)
    {
        setNome(nome);
        setCap(150);
    }

    Jogador() { }

    ~Jogador(void)
    {
    }

    int getCap(){
        return _cap;
    }

    void setCap(int v){
        _cap = v;
    }
}
```

Them my "Main" - when I set the value, when I'm following it in the debugger, it sets the value correctly, but when I access the game.getJogador().getCap() again, it has the default value 150.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     Jogador _player = Jogador("Kyore");
     Game game = Game(_player);

     while(true){
          std::cout << game.getJogador().getCap(); //print 150
          game.getJogador().setCap(100); //set cap to 100
          std::cout << game.getJogador().getCap(); //print 150 again
          break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Game` class, change this

```
Jogador getJogador() {
        return _jogador;
    }
```

to

```
Jogador& getJogador() {
        return _jogador;
    }
```

And add one more method only to read:

```
const Jogador& getJogador()const {
            return _jogador;
        }
```

**Update for the questions asked in the comment**

1. To fix your specific issue of value remaining as `150` inspite of setting a new value, converting the return type to `reference`  is enough. 
   **Why returning reference works?**  
    Because, whenever your original version of `getJogador()` is called, a copy of the object is
   created. Even though you are changing its value, you are actually
   changing the value of the temporary object created, not the original
   one. 
   So as your intention is to modify the original object, we need
   to access the original one, not its temporary copy. `Reference` is
   the better mechanism in such cases (`pointer` being the other mechanism, but less safer than `reference`)
2. Now about why I suggested the new over load of a `const member`
   function, returning a `const reference`: this is to highlight to you that it is possible to still get the object without changing its internal state unintentionally. 
   Your sample code does not differentiate between the two `getJogador()` functions. 
   So to understand, add these two functions to your `Game class`:

   `void DontManipulate()const { std::cout<<getJogador().getCap(); }`
   `void Manipulate() { std::cout<<getJogador().getCap(); }`

   See the compiler error(s) that you get: - it should throw light on the differences.
    Additionally, if you `std::cout` some message in both the `getJogador()` functions, you should be able to figure out the differences.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. For learn purpose, without the const method it wont work? And why? Wich one is called when I use the .getJogador()? The one returning the address or the const one? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't answer your comment immediately. Edited the answer now - check if it gives some more info so that you can figure out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `getJogador()` method.

In C++, objects can be passed "by value" - which is where the program (usually) copies the object's raw data into a new location, whereas in C# and Java objects are always passed by reference (not counting C#'s `struct`s which are passed by-value similar to C++). C++ will use the "copy constructor" to perform this copy. C++ will create the copy constructor if it isn't explicitly defined in your code, the signature has the form `ClassName(ClassName& other);`, the default (non-explicit) copy-constructor performs a shallow, member-wise copy operation.

In your case, your `getJogador` method is returning a copy of your `Jogador` instance field's data.

Change the method to return a reference or a pointer, like so:

```
Jogador& getJogador() const {
    return _jogador;
}
```

or

```
Jogador* getJogador() const {
    return &_jogador;
}
```

The `const` modifier informs the compiler that this method is not intended to modify the state of your `Game` class, so the compiler might perform certain optimizations as well as prevent successful compilation if the method does attempt to modify state.